# Spring Quartz: Disable Quartz scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

We have an service with a quartz scheduler.

This service can be scaled accordingly some needs.

**Our Quartz scheduler is not in a cluster mode.**

So, we need to able or disable scheduler according to an environment variable.

**Service can't be splitted in order to have two independent services.**

This is our related Quartz configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzSchedulerConfiguration {

    private static final String HOURLY_CRON_EXPRESSION = "0 0 * * * ?";
    private static final String MIDNIGHT_CRON_EXPRESSION = "0 0 0 * * ?";

    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(JobFactory jobFactory, Trigger[] fitxersJobTrigger)
            throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        factory.setTriggers(fitxersJobTrigger);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean loadPendingDocumentsJobDetail() {
        return createJobDetailFactoryBean(LoadPendingDocumentsJob.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean loadPendingDocumentsJobTrigger(
            @Qualifier("loadPendingDocumentsJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail) {

        long interval = jobsConfiguration.get().getParameters().stream()
            .filter(param -> "loadPendingDocumentsJobInterval".equals(param.getName()))
            .findAny()
            .map(param -> (Integer)param.getValue())
            .orElse(600000); // every 10 minutes

        LOG.debug("loadPendingDocumentsJobInterval = " + interval);
        return createIntervalTriggerFactoryBean(jobDetail, interval);
    }

    private  CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTriggerFactoryBean(JobDetail jobDetail, String expression) {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setCronExpression(expression);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    private JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetailFactoryBean(Class<? extends Job> jobClass) {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    private SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createIntervalTriggerFactoryBean(JobDetail jobDetail, long interval) {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(interval);
        factoryBean.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to create a service class to run a job. So I would use the @Scheduled annotation in spring which actually takes cron as a paramater e.g. @Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * ?") You can place this over any method then that you want to schedule. See further information here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` Annotation on your configuration class.